# How to direct attention of another SE site visitors to a relevant question on another SE site

Tags: support

Suppose I posted a question on an SE site. I know there are 2-3 other SE sites whose regular visitors would also be able to give good answers. How do I bring their attention to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could post the question in the main chat room of the other sites. That's probably the limit of what would be acceptable IMO.

Comment: how to access the chat room?

Comment: @user_1_1_1  Navigate to the site in question. Now scroll down to to the bottom of the page and look toward the left and you'll see a chat link. You can also access chat from the humburger menu icon in the top right once you're on that site.